# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv3d_1_input to have shape (704, 11, 3, 1) but got array with shape (72000, 704, 11, 3)

Tags: image, numpy, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am working on feeding images to a 3D convolutional network. The image is a 704 x 11 x 3 image, and I get the following error. The number of train images are 72000 and the input shape for the CNN is `(704,11,3,1)`.

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv3d_1_input to have shape (704, 11, 3, 1) but got array with shape (72000, 704, 11, 3)

Below is the code I have written in keras to feed to the network.

```python
x = cv2.imread(image_path)
print (x.shape)
x = np.reshape(x,(1, num_features))
data_x.append(x)
...

# After splitting to train and validation and test
...

train_x = data['train_x']
test_x = data['test_x']
validate_x = data['validate_x']

#Convert into float and normalize
train_x = train_x.astype('float32')
test_x = test_x.astype('float32')
validate_x = validate_x.astype('float32')
train_x = train_x.reshape(train_x.shape[0], 704, 11, 3).astype('float32')
test_x = test_x.reshape(test_x.shape[0], 704, 11, 3).astype('float32')
validate_x = validate_x.reshape(validate_x.shape[0], 704, 11, 3).astype('float32')
train_x = train_x/255
test_x = test_x/255
validate_x = validate_x/255
data['train_x'] = train_x
data['test_x'] = test_x
data['validate_x'] = validate_x

... 
train_x = np.expand_dims(train_x, axis=0)
validate_x = np.expand_dims(validate_x, axis=0)
test_x = np.expand_dims(test_x, axis=0)
...
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv3D(8, kernel_size = (3,3,3),data_format="channels_last", 
 activation = 'linear', input_shape=(704,11,3,1), padding='same'))
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the `axis`:

```
# makes train_x: (?, 704, 11, 3, 1)
train_x = np.expand_dims(train_x, axis=-1)
...
```

Also according to the error message, `train_x` has not been actually reshaped, so double check that this operation is in fact invoked.